# Is there any way I can achieve this in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm running an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I have this model class with a self-referencing association :

```
public class VehicleCategory 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentVehicleCategoryId")]
    public int? ParentVehicleCategoryId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual VehicleCategory ParentVehicleCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<VehicleCategory> subVehicleCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I have configured everything in EF to retrieve get all data and added this config into the `startup.cs` file to prevent looping:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
```

The problem is that when I try to get all data from the database, I end up with this json result :

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "description": "description 1",
    "parentVehicleCategoryId": null,
    "subVehicleCategories": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "description 2",
        "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
        "subVehicleCategories": null
      },
      {
       "id": 10,
        "description": "description 3",
        "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
        "subVehicleCategories": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "description": "description 2",
    "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
    "subVehicleCategories": null
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "description": "description 3",
    "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
    "subVehicleCategories": null
  }
]
```

Is there a way I can only have this data with only the array representing the children:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "description": "description 1",
    "parentVehicleCategoryId": null,
    "subVehicleCategories": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "description 2",
        "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
        "subVehicleCategories": null
      },
      {
       "id": 10,
        "description": "description 3",
        "parentVehicleCategoryId": 7,
        "subVehicleCategories": null
      }
    ]
  },
 
]
```

To get data I'm using this code:

```
var test = _raceContext.VehicleCategories
                       .Include(x => x.subVehicleCategories)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to include only top-level entities, and their children listed inside, you could use a `Where` clause to get only those where `ParentVehicleCategory` is `null`:

```
var test = _raceContext.VehicleCategories
                       .Where(vc => vc.ParentVehicleCategory == null)
                       .Include(x => x.subVehicleCategories)
                       .ToList();
```

This way, the top-level list is the "parent-less" entities, but the second-level entities will appear in your tree, because those entities are all children of some parent, and is included because of your call to the `Include` method. If you have only two levels of hierarchy, this method will work for you, but if a "child" entity can also be a "parent", you will need to do some extra work.

Comment: This would return only top and first level entities, and the rest levels will be missing.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was clear in my first sentence. But I edited my last paragraph to maybe add some clarity.